# Passing an array to a sort function in C language

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float smallest(int arr[],int k,int n);
void sort(int arr[],int n);

void main()
{
 int arr[20],i,n,j,k;
 clrscr();
 printf("\nEnter the number of elements in the array: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 printf("\nEnter the elements of the array");
 for(i=0 ; i < n ; i++)
 {
  printf("\n arr[%d] = ",i);
  scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
 }

 sort(arr,n);
 printf("\nThe sorted array is: \n");
 for(i=0 ; i < n ;  i++)
 printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
 getch();
}

int smallest(int arr[],int k,int n)//smallest function
{
 int pos=k,small=arr[k],i;
 for(i=k+1;i<n;i++)
 {
  if(arr[i]<small)
  {
   small=arr[i];
   pos=i;
  }
 }
 return pos;
}


void sort(int arr[],int n)//sorting function
{
 int k,pos,temp;
 for(k=0 ; k < n ; k++)
  {
   pos=smallest(arr,k,n);
   temp=arr[k];
   arr[k]=arr[pos];
   arr[pos]=temp;
  }
}
```

In the above program the sort function is being called from main but the return type of `sort` is void and it still returns the sorted array. As after sorting the array the function should return the sorted array back to the calling function to print the sorted array but the program runs perfectly. How is that happening?

Comment: you pass array to the function and the function works on that array directly since arrays in C are passed by reference. it doesn't return anything, it rather works on the argument being passed to it

Comment: @mangusta Arrays are not passed by reference.

Comment: @self statically declared arrays are passed by reference. functions too. everything else in C is passed by value

Comment: @mangusta Wrong, everything is passed by value. Arrays decay to pointers. You cannot pass a function, only a function *pointer*.

Comment: It is best to post compilable code. You need to revisit the C commenting conventions; `void sort(int arr[],int n)\\sorting function` is not the start of a function definition followed by a comment!  Since you use `<conio.h>`, you must be on Windows, so the `void main()` is permissible, but it is better to use `int main(void)` — or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` when you use command line arguments.

Comment: @self, well if we put things in this way then yes, everything decays to pointers but when we declare some array say `<type> array[size];` and pass `array`, the declared array itself is implied, not `&array[0]`. which means that it is not the duplicate of `array` that is passed, but rather the pointer to its first element

Comment: @mangusta: you cannot say `pass by reference`, there is nothing in C as `reference`, you can rather say `passed as pointer`. As *self* tries to explain, in C only pass by value is there.

Comment: @MadHatter right, `passed as pointer` describes it better

Comment: @all can any one post the correct answer? please. i think if arrays are passed by reference then there is no return required as said by mangusta

Comment: @user3056685 : Don't get confused, I think *TobiMcNamobi* explains it in nice way in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare

```
int arr[20];
```

you can say "arr is an array of 20 integers". But arr is a pointer to an integer as well, pointing to the first integer in a row of 20. So de-referencing `*arr` is an integer, the same as `arr[0]` in fact.

This means when you pass `arr` to a function you only pass a pointer to that function. The function in this case works on the (copied) pointer. But this very pointer points exactly to the same memory as your original `arr` declared in `main()`. And that's the reason why manipulating `arr` in `sort()` is in fact manipulating `arr` in `main()`.

Answer (score 4):

When passing an array as a parameter, this

```
int smallest(int arr[],int k,int n)
```

means exactly the same as

```
int smallest(int *arr,int k,int n)
```

For example

```
#include<iostream>
void printArray(int data[])
{
  for(int i = 0, length = sizeof(data); i < length; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << data[i] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int data[] = { 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2 };
  printArray(data);
  return 0;
}
```

You will see that only the first 4 elements of the array are printed. The `sizeof(data)` returns a value of 4! That happens to be the size of the pointer used to pass the array to `printArray()`.
First the array does not get copied. The pointer to the first element of the array is copied

Comment: @amit I hope now it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no connection between any function argument  what is, or is not passed using a `return` statement with an expression according to the function's return type.

While it is true that all parameter passing in C is by value - copy the value to a "local parameter variable" -  nothing is assumed about what is to happen at the memory location a *pointer* is referencing. So, a function can make any changes in the calling environment, even without returning a value.

As to parameters declared as being `aType name[]`. this is merely syntactic sugar for `const aType* name`.